# how to put a limit in input tag type number

Tags: angularjs, html, input

I have an tag input like this

```
<div class="form-group col-md-3">
     <label class="lb">Valor total</label> 
     <input type="number" ng-model="subTotalProduto"
            ng-keyup="calculaValorProdutos()"
            id="idValorTotalProdutoP"
            class="form-control "  />                     
 </div>
```

and i need to put a limit like `maxlength="15,4"`
being much more specific i need this in my input  `999999999999999,9999` or something like this mask `###############,####`

i iv tried to look at web but all sugest dosent work in my case.. i dont now why.. so i ask here.. 
its can be in angular, jquery

Comment: Number has a `min` and `max` that you can put on it.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-max

Comment: Have you tried using `pattern`?

Comment: Do not work the Pattern.. i dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
ng-pattern="/^\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,4})?$/"
```

It should work as a simple regular expression for testing if your input matches some specific pattern.

You can test it [here](https://www.regextester.com/?fam=102865)

And here is also a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/KHKa6M6HlF8qd6fKyffl?p=preview)

Comment: i try this and got this erro `Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at columns 0-0 [\] in expression [\d+(\.\d{15,4})?].`

Comment: `ng-pattern` expects a string or expression that returns a `RegExp`, you can either wrap the pattern in single quotes (`ng-pattern="'\d+(\.\d{15,4})?'"`) or use the literal regex notation (`ng-pattern="/\d+(\.\d{15,4})?/g"`)

Comment: i tried your two sugest but got other kind of erros `SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^d+(.d{15,4})?$/: numbers out of order in {} quantifier`

Comment: try this one `"/\d{1,15}\.\d{1,4}/g"`

Comment: now i dont got an erros but dosen´t work..  `input` continuos accepting a lot of numbers

Comment: finaly `^\d{1,15}\.?(\d{1,4})?`

Comment: oh sry not yet(

Comment: Now try ` ^\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,4})?`

Comment: But it does work on the test page I gave, isn't it? I guess you just need to correctly insert it into your `ng-pattern` directive

Comment: Try deleting for example `g` at the end or/and `/` from the beginning and ending or even try to insert it in single quotes like this `'\d{1,15}(\.\d{1,4})?'`

Comment: Check out my answer now, this is how you insert a regex in ng-pattern. Now should work :)

Answer (score 0):

seems a bit strange but this solution solved my question

```
 $(function() {
          $('#idValorTotalProdutoP, #idValorUnitarioProduto, #idProdutoQuantidade, #idValorIcmsNota,#idValorFreteNota, #idValorSeguroNota, #idValorTotalP, #idFunruralNota, #idValorTotalNotaProdutor, #idAlicotaIcmProduto, #idBaseCalculoProduto').on('change keyup input', function() {
            match = (/(\d{0,15})[^.]*((?:\.\d{0,4})?)/g).exec(this.value.replace(/[^\d.]/g, ''));
            this.value = match[1] + match[2];
          });
        });
```